# Android Lollipop DatePicker not working properly

Tags: android, datepicker

I run my app under 5.0 and works fine , but when i run on a device 5.0+ listener doesnt validate .

```
  DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener listener = new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                Date current = new Date(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

                if (current.getTime() < minDate.getTime()) {
                    view.updateDate(minDate.getYear(), minDate.getMonth(), minDate.getDate());
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen on several Samsung and Nexus devices running versions greater than Honeycomb, where onDateSet/onDateChanged weren't being called (or were even called multiple times). As a workaround, manually settings the positive action's click listener to trigger the method you want has worked pretty well.

For example, assuming you have `DatePickerDialog dateDialog`:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){ // Fix for some Samsung/Nexus devices not explicitly calling onDateSet
    dateDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            DatePicker datePicker = dateDialog.getDatePicker();
            listener.onDateChanged(datePicker, datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
        } 
    });     
}
```

You may also want to add a check within your onDateChanged() method to ensure that the date picker dialog is actually shown when handling the date changes, to prevent it from being called twice on certain devices. e.g.

```
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    if(!view.isShown()) return;

    // Safe to handle the date
}
```